# Module not found: Can't resolve 'moment' in 'node_modules\react-moment\dist' in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have installed react-moment 'npm i react-moment'. It is installed in the directory node_modules and dependency added in the package.json file. Every thing is correct. But when I import

```
import Moment from 'react-moment'
```

then it shows

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'moment' in 'node_modules\react-moment\dist'
```

But there is nothing wrong with this directory, I haven't modified the files inside react-moment directory in node_modules. Just after installing the package, when I import the package

```
import Moment from 'react-moment'
```

Then it shows the error.

Comment: It looks like you have to `npm i moment` too.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`moment` is a [peer dependency](https://github.com/headzoo/react-moment/blob/master/package.json#L67) of `react-moment`, which mean you have to install `moment` in you project as well (it doesn't ship with its own version of `moment`).

`npm i --save moment`

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me:

1. `npm install --save moment`
2. `npm install --save react-moment`
3. `npm install --save moment-timezone`

:)

Answer (score 2):

I sorted it out by adding the '--legacy-peer-deps' argument to the end of the command as the error message shows:

```js
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@13.3.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=13.0.0 <14.0.0" from @ng-select/ng-select@8.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select
npm ERR!     @ng-select/ng-select@"^8.0.0" from @ng-matero/extensions@13.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-matero/extensions
npm ERR!       @ng-matero/extensions@"^13.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     @ng-select/ng-select@"^8.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/yimin/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/yimin/.npm/_logs/2022-12-01T14_08_17_585Z-debug-0.log
```

```html
npm install --save moment --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue with [reac-datetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime) package and this one worked for me:

```
npm install --save moment
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are working with Timezone features make sure that you have installed the timezone package as well. if not paste the below npm code.

npm install --save moment-timezone