# Uncaught TypeError: moment is undefined . When using turbopack

Tags: next.js, next.js13, turbopack

I using moment-jalali in my own project and everything workes as expected , But when I configure --turbo in package.json file , After runing project by npm run dev browser console thrown an error:

[image]

After lookup in stack overflow site . I got some solutions but these doesn't works:
[Module not found: Can't resolve 'moment' in 'node_modules\react-moment\dist' in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137095/module-not-found-cant-resolve-moment-in-node-modules-react-moment-dist-in)